# Posting "Likes" on business page via business website

Tags: button, facebook-like

I have FB profile. I have created a business page. I have my business website with Like button. When I click on that button a post appears on my private profile but not on the business page.
How can I make "Likes" from my website appear on business page on Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to link the likes of the page directly to your facebook business page. Let me illustrate:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<h2>Connect with us</h2>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/yourbuzpage" data-send="false"     
data-layout="button_count" data-width="149" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana">  
</div>
```

Replace

```
data-href="http://www.facebook.com/yourbuzpage"
```

with the fan page you have created on facebook.com.

To change notification settings on facebook.com I would recommend you to visit https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/172901342767609/